# SELinux install error

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, selinux

I tried to install SELinux using the terminal with the following:

```
sudo apt-get install selinux
```

When it had finished, it said that there was an error. These are a few of the last lines which contained the error messages:

```
Starting SELinux autorelabel                                          [ OK ] 
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.1) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic
Selecting previously unselected package selinux-policy-ubuntu.
(Reading database ... 285160 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../selinux-policy-ubuntu_0.2.20091117-0ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking selinux-policy-ubuntu (0.2.20091117-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up selinux-policy-ubuntu (0.2.20091117-0ubuntu2) ...
Updating /etc/selinux/config.
Processing triggers for selinux (1:0.11) ...
semodule deferred processing now taking place
Error opening /etc/selinux/ubuntu/contexts/files/file_contexts.local: No such file or directory
libsemanage.sefcontext_compile: sefcontext_compile returned error code 255. Compiling /etc/selinux/ubuntu/contexts/files/file_contexts.local
libsemanage.semanage_install_active: Could not copy /etc/selinux/ubuntu/modules/active/file_contexts.homedirs to /etc/selinux/ubuntu/contexts/files/file_contexts.homedirs. (No such file or directory).
/usr/sbin/semodule:  Failed!
dpkg: error processing package selinux (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can anybody of you help me solve this problem?
Would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Just bumped into this-- Rebooting after I hit this point and then rerunning the install seems to have taken care of it.

```
$ sudo apt get install selinux
<snip>
usr/sbin/semodule: SELinux policy is not managed or store cannot be accessed.
Error opening /etc/selinux/ubuntu/contexts/files/file_contexts.local: No such file or directory
libsemanage.sefcontext_compile: sefcontext_compile returned error code 255. Compiling /etc/selinux/ubuntu/contexts/files/file_contexts.local
libsemanage.semanage_install_active: Could not copy /etc/selinux/ubuntu/modules/active/policy.kern to /etc/selinux/ubuntu/policy/policy.29. (No such file or directory).
/usr/sbin/semodule:  Failed!
dpkg: error processing package selinux (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 selinux
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

$ sudo reboot

$ sudo apt-get install selinux
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
selinux is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Setting up selinux (1:0.11) ...
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-30-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-30-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
 * Starting SELinux autorelabel                                      [ OK ]
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.2) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-30-generic

$ sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             ubuntu
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          permissive
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      28
```

Been a while since I've played with SELinux (and never on a debian-based distro), but my guess is that the install depends on something that's not running in the kernel by default and the reboot takes care of this.